# JavaScript Window Unload Not Working [Vanilla Javascript]

Tags: javascript

I came across a lot of similar questions on stack overflow, but the issue is that most of them are old (as in answered near about 3 to 4 years ago).

**PROBLEM**

I want to execute a function when the tab is closed (I want to use vanilla java-script) . I've tried doing the following:

```
// No.1 -> THROWS AN ERROR *Blocked alert('hello') before onunload*
window.onunload = function() {
  alert('hello');
}

// No.2 -> THROWS AN ERROR *Blocked alert('hello') before onunload*
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  alert('hello')
};
```

Way no.3 shown below works as it throws a dialog before leaving or reloading, but the issue is that it runs a function when we click "X" and try to close the tab but when the dialog appears which has two buttons **leave** and **cancel**.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.returnValue = '';
 bye();
});

function bye() {
 console.log('leaving');
}
```

The way presented above runs the function when we click on **"X"** but logically the function should run after we click on leave. Refer to the **Screenshot** below :

[image]

I need the function to execute after we click on **leave** or is there any other way to achieve this ?

PS: I am running **vue-js** but need plain JS solution

Comment: @MichaelGeary.. OK that means there is no possible way to detect that if the user closed the tab ?

Comment: I think this thread is worth a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect and I deleted it. That's what I get for commenting too early in the morning. :-) I posted an answer with a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, a combination of [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) and [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) event listeners may do the trick.

Note that there are many restrictions on what you can do inside these listeners; see the MDN links above for details. For example, as you found, you can not use `alert()` inside them. But you *can* write to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), for example.

Here is an example page that uses `localStorage` to save the time the page was last closed and display it when the page is loaded again. See if this is close to what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Remember Page Close Time</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    This page was last closed on:
    <span id="closetime">Never before</span>
</div>

<script>

    window.addEventListener( 'beforeunload', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = '';
    });

    window.addEventListener( 'unload', function( event ) {
        localStorage.setItem( 'closetime', '' + new Date );
    });

    const closetime = localStorage.getItem( 'closetime' );
    if( closetime ) {
        document.getElementById('closetime').innerText = closetime;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```